# id<NSCoding, NSCopying> to NSString

Tags: objective-c, nscoding, nscopying

I have some `NSURL *url` and I want to get its GenerationId:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [url resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLGenerationIdentifierKey] error:&error];
id generatonIdKey = dictionary[NSURLGenerationIdentifierKey]; //Returned as an id <NSCopying, NSCoding, NSObject> (read-only)
```

Now I want to display `generatonIdKey` by converting it to `NSNumber` or `NSString`.

Is it possible? If yes how?

Comment: `if ([generatonIdKey isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) { NSNumber *idAsNumber = (NSNumber *)generationIdKey; } else if ([generatonIdKey isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {NSString *idAsString = (NSString *)generationIdKey;}`?

Comment: @Larme `generatonIdKey` is `NSMutableData`

Comment: And what's its value? What is it supposed to mean? `NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:generationIdKey encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` make sense?

Comment: @It is some unique identifier. I think it does make sense.

Comment: @Larme Is it possible to convert `generatonIdKey` to `NSNumber`

Comment: It really depends on what is `generationIdKey`, how it was constructed etc. Do you have some sample values of it?

Comment: `generatonIdKey` looks like some data. You can get a displayable string with `[generatonIdKey description]`.